# How to retrieve tags from "Amazon Photos"?

Tags: metadata, tagging

I recently subscribed to Amazon Prime, which allows me to use Amazon Drive / Amazon Photos. With it, I can upload and store all my images, RAW files included.

I was surprised to see that Amazon Photos offers not only face recognition (nothing new) but also **object/context recognition** ! Going online, I can browse my images by tags, such as "sun", "ocean" or "smile".

Is it possible to retrieve those tags and adding them to the metadata of each image on my hard drive ?

Comment: Somewhat related on software recs site: [AI-based classification for local image](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/56827/1398)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked Amazon client support: **it is not possible**, but they "are glad to have received my request and have transmitted it to their team".

I also asked on the Amazon developper forum (not sure it is the best place), but so far no answer : https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/205330/retrieve-photo-tags-from-amazon-photos.html

Comment: Amazon probably wants to be careful offering any features that could make their features available as an engine to uninvited third parties.

Comment: @rackandboneman **The question is, Who are the invited parties ?**